# How to add text in bxslider banner?

Tags: javascript, bxslider

Add some text but design getting broke

[image]

Comment: Paste your code in question and show what you have tried so far rather giving link to code snapshot else this will lead to downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using CSS and adding an content div, you can achieve this, like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
    });
});
```

```css
.bannerDetail {
  color: #fff;
  top: 38px;
  left: 221px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```css
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" />
    <div class="textDetail">Funky roots</div>
  </li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" />
    <div class="textDetail">The long and winding road</div>
  </li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" />
    <div class="textDetail">Happy trees</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

WorkingExanple: http://codepen.io/JoyCoder/pen/JYgzNL

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion its working..
bt i need big text like h1 60px font-size

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the caption option in your jquery script.

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  captions: true
});

Answer (score 0):

The bxSlider API has the `captions` option:

```
$(function() {
    var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        captions: true
    });
});
```

On the images that require a caption, use the `title` attribute.

```
<img src="image.png" title="This is a caption"/>
```

http://bxslider.com/options#captions